# Why $\mathbb P(X_n=m)=F_{X_n}(m+1/2)-F_{X_n}(m-1/2)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ s.t. $P(X_n\in\mathbb Z)=1$. Let $F_{X_n}$ the distribution function of $X_n$. Since $X_n$ take it's value in $\mathbb Z$, we have that $F_{X_n}$ is constant and continuous on $[a+1,a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb Z$. Fix $m\in\mathbb Z$. Why $$\mathbb P(X_n=m)=F_{X_n}(m+1/2)-F_{X_n}(m-1/2)\ \ ?$$

Comment: Is $F_{X_n}$ the cumulative distribution function? If so, then $F_{X_n}(m+1/2)-F_{X_n}(m-1/2)$ is the probability that $X_n$ is less than $m+1/2$ minus the probability that $X_n$ is less than $m-1/2$. The only integer in that range is $m$, so this is exactly the probability that $X_n=m$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{X_n=m\}=\mathbb P\left\{m-\frac{1}{2}< X_n\leq m+\frac{1}{2}\right\}.$$

Comment: @Did: I in fact don't understand your edit... My first answer was wrong ?

Comment: The new RHS is $$F_X(m+1/2)-F_X(m-1/2)$$ while the former version was $$F_X(m+1/2)-\lim_{x\to m-1/2,x<m-1/2}F_X(x)$$ hence the new version does not need any supplementary explanation about the reason why, *in the present case*, $$F_X(m-1/2)=\lim_{x\to m-1/2,x<m-1/2}F_X(x)$$